# SD card not coming out of busy state after writing 512 bytes and times out

Tags: sd-card, pic, spi, firmware

I am using SD card (Delkin 2GB) in SPI mode on dsPIC33E MCU. Card is initializing properly in SPI mode. After writing 512 bytes of data and dummy 16 bit CRC to SD card, I am getting DATA_ACCEPTED (0x05) response from card. However, after this write, it goes in busy state forever and time out occurs. I could see data written in SD card. This problem doesn't occur for different 1 GB card.

Comment: So, where is your code and what is your question?